# how to set dynamic link library path and environment variable for a process in valgrind

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LD_PRELOAD and some environment variables for a process while running and detect memory leaks with Valgrind.

Can anyone suggest a way to set or pass these variable for a process in valgrind?.

Comment: Um, the same way you set any environment variables?

Answer (score 6):

I've run into a similar issue, trying to run `valgrind` on programs that need libraries incompatible with the ones `valgrind` uses, and have been using:

`valgrind --trace-children=yes env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=your_library_path OTHER_VAR=foo your_program arg1 arg2...`

[env](https://linux.die.net/man/1/env) sets up the environment and then [execs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) `your_program`.  We need to pass the [--trace-children=yes](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#opt.trace-children) argument to `valgrind` in order for it to continue to trace through the `exec` syscall.  Without `--trace-children=yes` set, valgrind will stop tracing at the `exec` and you won't get any useful output from `valgrind` on `your_program`.

One potential downside to this approach is that valgrind might report any memory issues in `env`.  I haven't seen any false positives from this source (`env` is not a very complicated program), but it could happen.

I haven't tried this with `LD_PRELOAD` though (it hasn't come up for my use-case yet).  `Valgrind` does set `LD_PRELOAD`, so you might have to do something like:

`valgrind --trace-children=yes env LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:your_preload your_program`

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with the standard mechanisms?  These include:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$new_libpath LD_PRELOAD=$new_preload OTHERVAR=otherval valgrind your.program arg1 …
```

Or:

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$new_libpath \
    LD_PRELOAD=$new_preload \
    OTHERVAR=otherval \
    valgrind ./your.program arg1 …
```

Or:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$new_libpath
export LD_PRELOAD=$new_preload
export OTHERVAR=otherval
valgrind ./your.program arg1 …
```

The advantage of the first two mechanisms is that it doesn't affect the working environment of your shell.  The advantage of the last mechanism is that it *does* affect the working environment of your shell (which makes it easier to run `valgrind` the next time — you don't have to remember to find the command with the environment in your history).

Comment: if i set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$new_libpath and LD_PRELOAD=$new_preload , it is giving segmentation fault in valgrind.As it is overriding the existing Library path and LD_PRELOAD for Valgrind. But my program normally runs without valgrind.

Comment: The new values can perfectly well include the old values (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/new/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc).  Is it `valgrind` that is crashing or your program?  If it is your program, is `valgrind` reporting on why it is crashing?  Why are you using `LD_PRELOAD` at all?  IMO, `LD_PRELOAD` is a dire, emergency-use only temporary band-aid — it should not be a routine part of the way you run programs.  If your program runs without `valgrind`, it should run OK with `valgrind`, albeit a little more slowly. Does it run without LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_PRELOAD? If so, why use them with `valgrind`?

Comment: Normally i run my program like (ENV1=.. ENV2=.. LD_LIBRARY_PATH=mylibpath LD_PRELOAD=mylib.so ./myprogram -myprogram-options)
It seems valgrind is crashing when i pass LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_PRELOAD and without these myprogram won't run. LD_PRELOAD and Lib path is required for myprogram at the initial time.Without valgrind and with gdb it works fine. But with valgrind it crashes and it is not reporting any error other than crash.

Comment: What does your preload do?  Replace memory allocation code?  IMNSHO, you should be upgrading your program so the LD_PRELOAD is not necessary.